# C++ template deduction failed for basic_string

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stdstring

I am struggling a bit with templates; I am trying to write a method that iterates over a range of strings, no matter their type or the container they are kept in. In the following code:

```
template<template<class> class ContainerType,
         typename CharType>
ContainerType<basic_string<CharType>>
foo(typename ContainerType<basic_string<CharType>>::iterator begin,
    typename ContainerType<basic_string<CharType>>::iterator end,
    CharType letter)
{
    return ContainerType<basic_string<CharType>>();
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    auto bar = foo(words.begin(), words.end(), 'a');
}
```

The compiler can't figure out the type of `ContainerType`.
I must say that I am a beginner when it comes to C++ templates.

Comment: `vector` has *two* template arguments... and did you mean `foo(words)`?

Comment: Look into variadic templates, you'll need them.

Comment: ...and why not use `for (auto & s : words)`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think he wants to know the container type, he's default constructing a container to return from the function

Comment: Your function arguments form a non-deductible context (i.e the container type can be deduced from the arguments).

Comment: @KerrekSB The Allocator type for vector has a default value...

Comment: @user1019710 it doesn't matter, it makes you fill them all out.

Comment: There's no way to deduce the type of container from a pair of iterators. Angew explained one reason, the other is that... iterators aren't meant for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply speaking, template argument type deduction only works to the right of the last `::`, if there is one. Imagine what you're telling the compiler:

I am calling `foo()` with a certain type. Now I want you to look at all single-parameter class templates which could possibly exist, try to instantiate each of them with all possible types, and see for which of these a nested typedef `iterator` matches the type I sent to `foo`. Then use that combination as template arguments.

I believe it's pretty obvious that doesn't work. That's why anything to the left of `::` is a non-deduced context, so template parameters in such context don't participate in template argument deduction. And since `foo` offers no other context, the argument cannot be deduced.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying... but is there any way for the compiler to deduce what I am trying to do? Maybe my syntax is wrong?

Comment: @user1019710 No, there is no way to deduce the container type from its iterator. You'd have to pass in the container itself.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I already realized and deleted the comment... :)\